# Gpg key server showing 'gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr' while installing rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, gnupg

I am trying to install rvm in my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and am getting error while installing gpg keys.

Command:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

Error:

```
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.dirmngr' failed: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

dirmngr is installed.

Comment: Seems like you are missing dirmngr - check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401547/gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-no-dirmngr#401548

Comment: already tried it

Answer (score 1):

You can run the same key using  Sudo Command I am Sure the run and perfectly wrok

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 7638D0442B90D010
```